# Win2012R2 RDS Host Session - how do I prevent external access for some users?

Tags: windows-server-2012, remote-desktop, windows-server-2012-r2

I've set up a Win2012R2 RDS Session Host farm.

Only some users must be allowed to log on outside our network (external) while everybody must be allowed to logon on internal network.

How can I do this?

Comment: How do you have it setup for remote access?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method would be to use a Remote Desktop Gateway. The Gateway can be fitted with multiple Connection Authorization Policies and Resource Authorization Policies (CAPs and RAPs) to define exactly *who* is allowed to connect to *what*. You could, for instance, create an Active Directory security group named "Internal Network Access" and assign that security group to the RD CAP/RD RAP that defines access to internal resources.

Comment: Ok that sounds like something I should look into :) Thanks!!